# WPF MouseDown Event

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have a visual tree that looks like this:

A `Border`, containing a `ScrollViewer`, which contains a `TexBlock`.

The `ScrollViewer` takes up 100% of the space of the `Border`, and the `TextBlock` may or may not take up 100% of the space of the `ScrollViewer` depending on how the user configures it.

I want to capture a `MouseDown` event for when a user clicks anywhere in the `Border`. When I register a `MouseDown` event for either the `Border`, or the `ScrollViewer`, the callback does not get invoked. When I register a `MouseDown` event to the `TextBlock`, the callback does get invoked, but of course only in the clickable area of the `TextBlock` and not the full area of the `Border`.

One idea that I have is to create some sort of top level element that will go over the whole control, set it's visibility to hidden, then get the `MouseDown` from that.

Any suggestions? If something is not clear about this question let me know and I will fix it.

Showing Example code per request

```
// Need to know when a user clicks on anything inside of the border, but the 
// because there are items above it, the mouse event doesn't get invoked.
Border border = new Border();
ScrollViewer viewer = new ScrollViewer();
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();

border.Content = viewer;
viewer.Child = textBlock;
```

Comment: Can you please show some code

Comment: @FlatEric The code is too complex to show in one page. Like I hinted at, this is a part a user configurable application so it's pretty dynamic and abstracted. I'm not using XAML either. Best I can do is create some code that would be more simple to show and that is the same thing that I am talking about.

Comment: Nobody wants you to post your full code. You need to distill the question down to [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, and also include a precise, detailed explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register `PreviewMouseDown` event on the `Border`. It will also fire if a containing element is clicked.

```
private void Border_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  var clickedElement = e.OriginalSource;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more approach (although not that clean IMO) but it could be a useful if you require some custom behavior... maybe :)

We create custom scroll viewer and then use it instead of the standard one, our custom control will just propagate it's mouse down event to it's parent (*this example is oversimplified so it's not suitable for use in production in the current state*).

```
public class CustomScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
{
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ((e.Source as FrameworkElement).Parent as UIElement).RaiseEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Some info for people like me that weren't familiar with the `PreviewMouseDown` approach - it's using **Routing strategy** called **Tunneling** (from top to bottom) which is the opposite of **Bubbling** (from bottom to top)